# How to show that If $||Ax||\ge C||x||$ then $A$ is one-to-one a and range $A$ is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H,K$ be Banach spaces and $A$ a linear and continuous transformation  from $H$ to $K$ ($A\in B(H,K)$). How do I show that if $||Ax||\ge C||x||$, then $A$ is one-to-one and range $A$ is closed?

**Thanks  for Any Hint**

Answer (score 1):

One to one: Suppose $x\in \ker A$, then $Ax=0$. So the inequality says something is less than or equal to $0$, and you know that something is also...

Closed image: Suppose $Ax_n$ is a sequence in image, converging to some $y$ in $K$. Then in particular $Ax_n$ is Cauchy in $K$, so that means, since $||Ax_n||\ge C||x_n||$, $x_n$ is Cauchy in $H$. That means $x_n$ converges to some $x$ in $H$, as $H$ is complete. So by boundedness $Ax_n\to Ax=y$ by uniqueness of limit so $y$ is in range of $A$